# ios protocol not functioning properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, protocols

```
//AddSideBarProtocol.h
@protocol AddSideBarProtocol  <NSObject>

- (IBAction)barButtonTapped:(id)sender;

@end
```

I am creating above protocol to use in all my view controllers.
My implementation for this protocol is as follows:

```
//AddVehicleViewController.m
- (IBAction)barButtonTapped:(id)sender{
[self.view endEditing:YES];
[lblToolBarTitle setText:@"Vehicle Management"];

tblViewSideBar = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, self.view.frame.size.height-44)];
tblViewSideBar.delegate = self;
tblViewSideBar.dataSource = self;
tblViewSideBar.separatorStyle = UITableViewCellSeparatorStyleNone;
[tblViewSideBar setBackgroundColor:[UIColor lightGrayColor]];

btnToClose = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height)];
[btnToClose setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[btnToClose addTarget:self action:@selector(dismissView:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

addSideBarView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 44, 200, self.view.frame.size.height)];
[addSideBarView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

addSideBarView.frame = CGRectMake(-200, 44, 200, self.view.frame.size.height);

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^ {
                     addSideBarView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 200, self.view.frame.size.height);
                 }
                 completion:nil];

[self.view addSubview:btnToClose];
[self.view addSubview:addSideBarView];
[addSideBarView addSubview:tblViewSideBar];

}
```

And I am calling the protocol from another view controller named "MaintenanceViewControlle" using following lines of code::

```
AddVehicleViewController *addVehicle = [[AddVehicleViewController alloc] init];

id <AddSideBarProtocol> addSide;
addSide = addVehicle;

[addSide barButtonTapped:sender];
```

But This protocol is not functioning properly, so where am I lacking ??

Comment: What is the error u r getting?

Comment: I am not getting any error but this method is used to add a view when a button is tapped, that view is not adding using protocol.

Comment: Why the cast of addVehicle to addSide ? Why not doing [addVehicle barButtonTapped:sender] ?
If you have correctly put <AddSideBarProtocol> in your AddVehicleViewController.h you shouldn't have error/warnings

Comment: @KIDdAe:: If I use your solution then what is the meaning of declaring protocol, I can call that method without declaring protocol.
I have already tried your solution but it is not working, the same problem occurs as I mentioned in above comment.

Comment: Just casting is not going to change anything.. Protocol function (barButtonTapped:) should be implemented in each of your class where u want to call barButtonTapped function

Comment: @BKC:: Why I need to implement it in all classes, I have implemented in a class and just want to use it in another classes by using protocol.

Comment: Create a base class and add <AddSideBarProtocol> in header file for all your classes. Then you can implement it in 1 class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote from Apple :

> A class interface declares the methods and properties associated with that class. A protocol, by contrast, is used to declare methods and properties that are independent of any specific class.

How this work :

1) You declare your protocol (like you did)
2) You add in your interfaces that they implement this protocol
ex :

```
//AddVehicleViewController.h
@interface AddVehicleViewController : UIViewController <AddSideBarProtocol>
```

This means that this class should implement methods declared in your protocol.
You'll have warnings if you don't implement all methods not declared as optional in each of these classes.

3) You use it in your code :
ex :

```
AddVehicleViewController *addVehicle = [[AddVehicleViewController alloc] init];
[addVehicle barButtonTapped:sender];
```

Some reading about protocols :
[Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithProtocols/WorkingwithProtocols.html)

Comment: `barButtonTapped:`is called ? There are many views in your method, which one does not appear ?

Comment: yes that method is called and executed properly and none of the view is appearing.

Comment: This method should be called by the visible controller (`[self.view addsubview:aView]`has no meaning otherwise).
In your last code snippet, it seems that you call your method before showing the controller.

Comment: I didn't understand your point, can you please explain how to do it ??

Comment: I mean that on this line
`AddVehicleViewController *addVehicle = [[AddVehicleViewController alloc] init];`
The view of addVehicle is not added to the current view, then the lines like `[self.view addSubview:btnToClose];` in your method have no effect (since self is addVehicle and is not displayed).
I don't know what you're trying to achieve, but it seems that `MaintenanceViewController` should be the one that must implement your protocol and call the method. (he is the one displayed right ?)

Comment: yes maintenanceViewController is calling method using protocol and adding a view to display a table view in it and other outlets.

Comment: maintenanceViewController is not calling this method in your code snippet

Comment: I have changed the code a bit and yes now that method is not calling.

Comment: Now that method is calling but table view delegate methods are not calling, I think thats why my view is not adding, whats your solution ??

Comment: Please update your question's code.
Your delegate method are not called because the tableview is not in the view hierarchy?